# Как вносить данные и сохранять в открытый лист excel load_workbook.Когда он закрыт всё работает

Tags: python

```
# xl = Dispatch("Excel.Application")
# xl.Visible = True  # otherwise excel is hidden
# #Так он работает
# wb = xl.Workbooks.Open(r'C:\\Users\\Alexandr\\Desktop\\HERE.xlsx')
# sheet = wb.Worksheets[2]
# val = sheet.Cells(5,5).Value = 'Нет'
# print(val)


wb = load_workbook('C:\\Users\\Alexandr\\Desktop\\HERE.xlsx')  # Загружает файл
sheet = wb.worksheets[2]
for i in range(10000, 0, -1):  # Начало отсчёта с последней  строки числового значения
    z = sheet['I' + str(i)].value
    if z is None:
        i = +1
    else:
        i = i + 1
        z = sheet['I' + str(i)].value = "KKKKK"  # КА 02 ГРЩ01  06:00 J  #Ввод значения
        break

wb.save('C:\\Users\\Alexandr\\Desktop\\HERE.xlsx')
```

Comment: подозреваю, что никак. и питон здесь совершенно ни при чём.

Comment: wb = xl.Workbooks.Open c этим справляется .Но там не проходит код итерации по ячейкам, который работает в load workbook